# OpenShift Playground 4.5 and 4.7 Login

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

The current version of the OpenShift Playground which lasts for 60' is 4.5, and 4.7. I tried both of them when I press the copy login command to use my visual studio code to log in to it, I could not do it. It's saying that I cannot reach the address:

```
This site can’t be reachedCheck if there is a typo in oauth-openshift.apps-crc.testing.
If spelling is correct, try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
```

I want to use the OpenShift container platform to add an operator to the operators hub. But seems like hosting one is quite spicy for the price.

Comment: What does your login command look like (without the confidential part)?

Comment: I didn't have one, it was suppose to provide one when you go to the page via the button: "copy login command"

Comment: Does this still persist?